# How to know which SMS port?

Tags: android, sms

I am getting an SMS in Android application, but I have no idea how to know which port it sent on. BroadcastReceiver receiving all SMS messages, please tell me how to know SMS's port?

```
<data android:port="????" />
```

what number should be there?

Best Regards,
Ekaterina

Comment: define "port" in the question

Comment: hmmm so you are talking about `<data>` element of `<intent-filter>` element?   you shouldn't touch it ... if fact you should include this element `<data>`at all

Comment: No. I am talking about SMS's port

Comment: you have in the question `<data android:port="????" />` ... how it is connected with "SMS's port" (whatever you mean by "SMS's port") ... Maybe I'm not an Android's expert but have some knowladge about android and I have no f** idea what is a "SMS's port"

Comment: Read this http://www.ozekisms.com/index.php?owpn=221

Comment: @Selvin he means the socket port that sms uses.

Answer (score 0):

Ports are only relevant to data SMS, and all port-addressed messages are handled as data SMS in Android. A regular text message won't have a port associated with it.

If you want to receive port-addressed messages, you'll need a Receiver configured for data SMS. This Receiver needs a filter for the  `"android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED"` action, rather than the `"android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"` action for regular text messages. The data scheme is `"sms"`, and the data port can be a specific port number, or the wildcard `"*"` to listen on all ports. For example:

```
<receiver android:name=".DataSmsReceiver"> 
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
        <data android:scheme="sms"
              android:port="*" /> 
    </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

If you're listening on multiple/all ports and need to distinguish them in the Receiver, the port number can be retrieved from the data `Uri` on the `Intent` passed into the `onReceive()` method. For example:

```
int port = intent.getData().getPort();
```